# Invalid 'dimnames' given for data set

Tags: r, pca

I have selected a few columns of my original dataset with the code:

```
envfriend <- data.l1[c("eb_1","eb_2","eb_33","eb_34","eb_35","eb_36","eb_transpo","eb_read","eb_notetaking","eb_beverage","eb_breakfast","eb_lunch","eb_dinner")]
```

When I then try to conduct a Principal Components Analysis on this new dataset (it's a data.set, not data.frame), I get the error:

```
Error in `dimnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = dimnames) :
invalid 'dimnames' given for data set
```

I have tried to remove the names/dimnames, but that reveals a similar error. Why are my `dimnames` invalid? How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you make a small reproducible example of what you're experiencing?

Comment: You say this is not a data.frame. What is a "data.set" and what package is used to manage such objects?

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you're using `data.set` from the "memisc" package. If this is the case, you should be able to solve your problem just by wrapping your `data.set` in `as.data.frame`, as suggested under `?data.set`.

Here is an example using the *USArrests* dataset that comes with R. I've created a `data.set` version and tried to run `princomp` and get the error you mention.

This is how `princomp` works on the original **`data.frame`**.

```
princomp(USArrests, cor = TRUE)
# Call:
# princomp(x = USArrests, cor = TRUE)
# 
# Standard deviations:
#    Comp.1    Comp.2    Comp.3    Comp.4 
# 1.5748783 0.9948694 0.5971291 0.4164494 
# 
#  4  variables and  50 observations.
```

Now, let's create a **`data.set`** version:

```
library(memisc)
ARRESTS <- data.set(USArrests)
rownames(ARRESTS) <- rownames(USArrests)
```

This is where you get your error:

```
princomp(ARRESTS, cor = TRUE)
# Error in `dimnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = dimnames) : 
#   invalid 'dimnames' given for data set
```

And this is how you can try to solve it:

```
princomp(as.data.frame(ARRESTS), cor = TRUE)
# Call:
# princomp(x = data.frame(ARRESTS), cor = TRUE)
# 
# Standard deviations:
#    Comp.1    Comp.2    Comp.3    Comp.4 
# 1.5748783 0.9948694 0.5971291 0.4164494 
# 
#  4  variables and  50 observations.
```

---

Note from the above that I was able to modify the `rownames` of the `data.set`, while you mentioned you were getting similar errors in those cases. My *guess* is that you were trying to set them to `NULL`, which wouldn't work. From the "Note" section at `?dimnames`:

> Setting components of the dimnames, e.g., `dimnames(A)[[1]] <- value` is a common paradigm, but note that it will not work if the value assigned is `NULL`. Use `rownames` instead, or (as it does) manipulate the whole dimnames list.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should follow the structure as follows:

```
train.data -> should be a matrix  
train.label -> should be a numeric vector
```

Check these two and hopefully it should work.